# Can someone explain to me how Sal expanded the square in this example?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> $x^2-2x\color{blue}{+1}=24\color{blue}{+1}$
>
> We can now rewrite the left side of the equation as a squared term.
>
> $(x-1)^2=25$

So I'm not really sure how the equation on the top (which I know how he got) was written, or expanded in $(x - 1)^2 = 25$.

The $25$ bit is obviously $24 + 1$ and the $-1$ bit is obviously the $+1$ he added. However, I'm not sure were the $x$ came AND the negative sign (eg shouldn't it be $+1$ not $-1$ ? ). Why is there no $-2x$ aswell ? What are the steps involved in obtaining the expanded result?

Regards,

Comment: $(a-b)^2=a^2-2ab+b^2$

Answer (score 2):

Your question is why
$$x^2-2x+1=(x-1)^2?$$

Because 
$$(x-1)^2=(x-1)(x-1)=x(x-1)-(x-1)=x^2-x-x+1=x^2-2x+1.$$

In general,
$$x^2-(a+b)x+ab=(x-a)(x-b),$$
$$x^2-2ax+a^2=(x-a)^2.$$
Yours is the $a=1$ case.

Answer (score 2):

Recall that $$(\color{red}a-\color{blue}b)^2=\color{red}a^2-2\color{red}a\color{blue}b+\color{blue}b^2\tag{1}$$
We can write  $x^2-2x+1$ as: $$\color{red}x^2-2\color{red}x\cdot\color{blue}1+\color{blue}1^2.$$ We then use $\text{(1)}$ to conclude that $$\color{red}x^2-2\color{red}x\cdot\color{blue}1+\color{blue}1^2=(\color{red}x-\color{blue}1)^2.$$

Answer (score 1):

He uses the formula: $(a - b)^2 = a^2 -2 a b + b^2$